# Access form data in C# controller from AJAX post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am sending form data to a c# controller using AJAX, however I don't know how to access the data inside the controller. I am trying to pass the form data into the controller as a Person object but I am just returning system.Models.Person. I am new to C# so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Javascript

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetFormData',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {formData: formData},
        success: function(resultData){
            console.log(resultData)
        },
        error: function(){
            //do something else
        }
    })
}
```

Model

```
public class Person 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public string GetFormData(Person formData)
{
    string name = formData.name.ToString();

    return name;

}
```

Comment: Why to post your form via js ajax if you can do it directly in view with Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: Generally looks ok, so the question is: what exactly is `formData` after `const formData = new FormData(e.target);`?

Comment: Start with something simple, `public string GetFormData(string name)` and `data: {name: "test"}` - then `public string GetFormData(string name, int age)` *then* `(Person formData)`

Comment: formData is an object of key value pairs, with the keys being the name given to the inputs on my form, so I can do console.log(formData.get(‘name’)) and get the user’s name, but for some reason console.log(formData) returns an empty object. So I presume I’m passing an empty object into the controller but I don’t know how I would fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following post will help you

[Post Data Using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.compilemode.com/2016/04/passing-view-values-to-controller-using-asp-net-mvc.html)

Your code should be

**Model class Person.cs**

```
 public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery function to get the form data, I am assuming here you have submit button on your form

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () { //Your Submit button
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: "Home/GetFormData", // Controller/View 
                data: { //Passing data
                    name: $("#txtname").val(), //Reading text box values using Jquery 
                    age: $("#txtage").val(),
                }

            });

    });
});
```

Your HomeController method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFormData(Person obj)
    {
        string name = obj.name;
        string age = obj.age;
        //Once you have data here then you can pass anywhere i.e. database or some other method

        return View();
    }
```

Form values in the controller

[image: Values in the controller method]

Let me know, if any clarification required.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the help! I managed to solve it by creating an object of key value pairs from FormData and using JSON.stringify() to send it with Ajax, then I could access it in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use serialize if you will send form values:

```
$form = $(this).serialize();
```

Use FormData if you be sending a file for upload and alike.

And on your data declaration, set it as is (without declaring it as a literal JS object)

```
data: $form
```

The final code would look like this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$form = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/GetFormData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form,
    success: function(resultData){
        console.log(resultData)
    },
    error: function(){
        //do something else
    }
})
```